# What framework is suited for new product development which are more research and development sort of?

Tags: scrum, agile, agile-coach

I am working on multiple projects. One of the projects is all about research and development. Like the developer cannot give me the timelines for when it will be finished. Also, the developer doesn't know what needs to be done in the smaller steps. These tickets are historically created as design spikes for completing 1 sprint. I don't know what is the best way I can tackle it so that the progress can be measured and I can do some forecasting. What is the best framework or process to tackle such work?

Comment: Progress towards what? R&D can be done with many frameworks. This question has been asked and answered before (please search). Unless you can articulate a specific set of circumstances, this question is likely to be closed as an opinion poll.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want a framework to begin with? A framework may give you a good starting point, but one aspect of agility is "uncovering better ways of developing software by doing it and helping others do it".

That said, in an environment with a lot of uncertainty, I would recommend looking in two places for inspiration:

- [Lean Startup](http://theleanstartup.com/) has ideas for testing hypothesis, delivering rapidly, and getting information about real-world usage of the thing you are building.
- Flow-based approaches like [Dan Vacanti's Kanban](https://prokanban.org/) or [David J. Anderson's Kanban Method](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984521402) can help to eliminate waste in the process and increase the rate of feedback without the need for planning days and weeks in advance.